# Would a train stop if someone runs after it?

Tags: trains

I have seen many people miss trains and wave after it, but it doesn't stop, I'm in the UK and I am wondering if the train would stop in other countries or if it depends on the driver and the train company (in the UK)?

Comment: This would likely vary significantly by country.

Comment: On the DLR, there's no chance.

Comment: This is a typical 'list' question that is frowned upon on SE sites; the possible number of countries/drivers/companies is endless. Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: So the driver is going to make the train late and open the doors with half the train past the platform so you can run after it and be let on? I'm sure it can and does happen sometimes, because people do all sorts of things around the world (there are still trains in remote areas that will stop in the middle of nowhere for you, including in Canada, though that requires advance planning), but this strikes me as the sort of thing that would be strictly prohibited by a safety-minded railway.

Comment: It's certainly not impossible, but I suspect that people are actually just expressing frustration.

Comment: I run after a train when I wave goodbye to someone on it :-)

Comment: In Germany they don't wait for you even if you are on the track pressing the button to open the door....

Comment: The Metro North trains in the US may re-open the doors for a running passenger, but once it starts moving you are too late.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Not *quite* true, depends on everything from the driver’s current mood to the company and type of train. I even had a regional train (DB) which was already departing stop again, let me board and move off again (this was in Weilheim(Oberbay) and the train was a 628).

Answer (score 5):

Never seen it happen and really do not think it would be practical. It takes quite a lot of power to move a train and its inertia means that it takes a long time to stop.

One would not only have to stop the train and, depending on regulations, move it back to the platform to open the doors and allow boarding. The train would depart again later and everyone would be late just for one person, so it is not good for logistics. Might even delay an incoming train in stations where a platform is shared by multiple routes.

It is possible that there is a train somewhere that would stop for a late passengers but certainly expect this not to be the norm.

Comment: I have seen it once, a TGV in France, in the 1990's. I got the impression that the guy they stopped for was a friend or maybe employer of the staff on the platform.

Comment: When I took [the train to Moosonee, Ontario](http://www.ontarionorthland.ca) quite some time ago they made unscheduled stops at mileposts in the middle of absolutely no where to pick up gear and people who seemed to have been camping for hunting and/or fishing. I'm not sure how they arranged that but it seemed like they just flagged the train to stop at a place where the train was moving slowly anyway.